# SOLR export expression with field of type UUIDField returns java.util.UUID:46d49d49-ac91-49fc-b3c4-79d70e16c744

Tags: solr, export, streaming, uuid

Export expression with field of type UUIDField (fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true")  returns in the result set the type of the field and then the value, for example:

this query:

```
*search(Schema1,q="uuidFieldName:[* TO *]",fl="uuidFieldName,Time",sort="Time 
asc",qt="/export")*
```

returns:

```
{
  "result-set": {
    "*docs": [
      {
        "uuidFieldName": [
          "java.util.UUID:46d49d49-ac91-49fc-b3c4-79d70e16c744"
        ],
        "Time": "2019-01-21T16:08:03.979Z"
      },
      {
        "uuidFieldName": [
          "java.util.UUID:3dfdaed7-8060-4caa-af63-75cd064dd0e0"
        ],
        "Time": "2019-01-21T16:08:03.979Z"
      },
      {
        "EOF": true,
        "RESPONSE_TIME": 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would expect the value to be just the GUID and not: "java.util.UUID:3dfdaed7-8060-4caa-af63-75cd064dd0e0"

Any idea?

Comment: Which version of Solr? Have you tried with a more recent version? (that seems to be a `toString()` representation of the UUID object)

Comment: solr version 7.6.0. didnt try higher version